# How to ignore FAIL during conftest policy check in atlantis

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego, conftest, atlantis

I am still in the testing phase and would like to allow merging  of my PR even if the policy_check is FAIlING. What flag I can pass to enable that ?
My current config:

```yaml
  repos:
  - id: /.*/
    workflow: custom
    apply_requirements: [mergeable]
    allow_custom_workflows: true
    allowed_overrides: [apply_requirements, workflow]
  policies:
    owners:
      users:
        - XXX
    policy_sets:
      - name: conftest
        path: /atlantis/conftest_policies/policies/
        source: local
  workflows:
    custom:
      plan:
        steps:
          - init
          - plan
      policy_check:
        steps:
          - show
          - policy_check:
              extra_args: ["--update", "git::https://${serviceVariable.SAMPLE_TOKEN}@github.com/Company/conftest-policy.git", "--all-namespaces" ]
```

This is my output during atlantis plan:

```
exit status 1
Checking plan against the following policies: 
  conftest
? - <redacted plan file> - gcp.common - no policies found
FAIL - <redacted plan file> - gcp.iam - Service Account User and Service Account Token Creator roles are prohibited at the project level and must be assigned to specific service accounts. service_account_iam_roles uses the role roles/iam.serviceAccountUser.

38 tests, 36 passed, 1 warning, 1 failure, 0 exceptions`
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it by passing '--no-fail' flag

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use `warn` rule instead of `deny` rule in the rego policy

See this example where the `terraform_remote_state` is found and warned on instead of denied.

```
package evil_sources

import future.keywords

data_sources := {"terraform_remote_state"}

warn contains sprintf(message, [key]) if {
    message := "This data source is evil (%s)"

    input.data[key]
    key in data_sources
}
```

This way you can simply throw a warning (exit 0) to avoid having to set `--no-fail` globally on conftest

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation

> Any failures need to either be addressed in a successive commit, or
> approved by a blessed owner. This approval is independent of the
> approval apply requirement which can coexist in the policy checking
> workflow. After an approval, the apply can proceed.

[screenshot from Atlantis docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iyUi.png)